# Ruby metaprograming date ".at_beginning_of_X"

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

I have a method that outputs a type of timeframe, which can be any one of:
`["day", "week", "month"]`

How could I define a method that would output something like:
`type = "day"`
`Date.today.at_beginning_of_type`

Where `type` can be any of the three types I mentioned above?

**Edit:**  although it's a tiny method, here's the approach I've taken so far:

```
def output_a_date
 type = get_period_type
 puts 'The date at the beginning of the "#{type}" ago was "#{Date.today.at_beginning_of_type}"'
end

def get_period_type
  type = "day"
end
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It sounds like you're asking us how to write your code. Instead, why not show us a minimal example of what you tried and we'll help fix it. As is your question is out of scope as it's too broad, so please reduce it to a much narrower problem please.

Comment: Why not look to the implementations of [ActionView::DateHelper](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/HEAD/actionview/lib/action_view/helpers/date_helper.rb#L92) or GNU date for inspiration?

Comment: yeah I could have certainly done a better job in my initial writeup, sorry about that. I've updated with a sample method which reflects where I've tried to take it so far

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use the `send` method.

You can read more about it [here](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Object.html#method-i-send)

Your code might look like:

```
def beginning_of(type)
  Date.today.send(:"at_beginning_of_#{type}")
end
```